# Concat row values if they match?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 Text - words |
| 2 | A1 Text - wordsa |
| 3 | B1 Sentence - sentence |
| 4 | B1 Sentence - sentence b |

What I'm trying to achieve:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 Text - words, A1 Text - wordsa |
| 2 | B1 Sentence - sentence, B1 Sentence - sentence b |

I'm not sure how to approach this or is there a function that would deal with this? I need at least a suggestion to get started.

EDIT - I updated the table slighty. As ofcourse I don't want to aggregate the entire table into 1 row, hopefully the tables show what I'm trying to say more clearly.

Comment: How do you determine if they "match"?

Comment: Can I check the value and compare to the next row? Or would that be too expensive resource-wise?

Comment: Why do the `B1` sentences have an ID of `2` in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1:

If you want to find chains of successive rows with where the start of the string matches the next string then you can use a hierarchical function and collate the rows using `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS id,
       SUBSTR(
         SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Text, ', '),
         3
       ) AS Text
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH
       id IN (SELECT id
              FROM   table_name
              WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
              AND    LEVEL = 1
              CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                     PRIOR text LIKE text || '%'
             )
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       text LIKE PRIOR text || '%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Text) AS
SELECT 1, 'A1 Text - words' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A1 Text - wordsa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B1 Sentence - sentence' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'B1 Sentence - sentence b' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | TEXT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A1 Text - words, A1 Text - wordsa |
> | 3 | B1 Sentence - sentence, B1 Sentence - sentence b |

---

#### Option 2:

From Oracle 12, if you want to find the first string and then all the strings that also start with that first string then you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT MIN(first_id) AS id,
       LISTAGG(text, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY text) AS text
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY text
  MEASURES
    FIRST(id) AS first_id,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (matches+)
  DEFINE matches AS (text LIKE FIRST(text) || '%')
)
GROUP BY mno
```

Which, for the sample data, gives the same output (but may give a different output if there was more data as Option 1 is finding individual paths through the hierarchy and Option 2 is finding all children that match an ancestor).

In earlier versions, you should get the equivalent result using:

```sql
SELECT root_id AS id,
       LISTAGG(text, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS text
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS root_id,
         id,
         text
  FROM   table_name
  START WITH
         id IN (SELECT id
                FROM   table_name
                WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
                AND    LEVEL = 1
                CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                       PRIOR text LIKE text || '%'
               )
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         text LIKE PRIOR text || '%'
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY text
)
GROUP BY root_id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f865f6e9f511231952681d764931d759)*